# error: passing 'const string' as this argument of push_back

Tags: c++, string

I am getting the titular error in the following code in line 19

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

namespace robot_name 
{
    vector<string> allRobotNames;
    class robot
    {
        public:
            string robotName;

            string name() const
            {
                if(robotName.empty())
                {
                    robotName.push_back('a'+rand()%26);//this line
                    robotName.push_back('a'+rand()%26);//also here
                    robotName+=to_string(rand()%10) + to_string(rand()%10) + to_string(rand()%10);//and here
                    return robotName;
                }
                else
                {
                    return robotName;
                }
            };

            void reset() const
            {
                allRobotNames.push_back(robotName);
                while(find(allRobotNames.begin(), allRobotNames.end(), robotName)!=allRobotNames.end())
                {
                    robotName="";//here as well
                    robotName.push_back('a'+rand()%26);
                    robotName.push_back('a'+rand()%26);
                    robotName+=to_string(rand()%10) + to_string(rand()%10) + to_string(rand()%10);
                };
            };
    };
};
```

Also, similar errors in lines 20, 21, and 35. The class is instantiated like `const robot_name::robot robot` and then `robot.name()` is called as shown. I have done other code where the class is instantiated in the same way, however I did not get this error. Could someone check this for possible errors and tell me of some possible solutions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason for the semicolons after all closing brackets?

Comment: The member functions `name()` and `reset()` are declared `const` but try to modify a member variable. Don't do that.

Comment: No, I am just overly cautious. I didn't know which brackets I should have semicolons after, so I just put them on all of them.

Comment: @twerk_it_606, You put them after class definitions. Those are the only curly brace place and that's because you can define variables there.

Comment: CaptainObvlious if I take the const delclarations off, it says `error: passing const robot_name::robot as 'this' argument of std::string robot_name::robot::name() discards qualifiers.`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, Oh, dang. I was looking at the wrong declaration.

Comment: @twerk_it_606, Your `name` function modifies the object. Calling it on a `const` object makes no sense.

Comment: @twerk_it_606: _"I didn't know which brackets I should have semicolons after, so I just put them on all of them."_ So, programming by guessing? Avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` and `reset` functions are `const`.  This means that you cannot change any members within those functions.  For example, you're doing so at the `allRobotNames.push_back` function.

Either make `reset` and `name` non-const functions , or declare `robotName` as `mutable`:

```
mutable string robotName;
```

However don't abuse `mutable`.  Only if it makes sense to use `mutable` should you use it (for example, there is no change in the object that would impact the user of the object).

If you're using `mutable` to just make it possible to change the values of class members, that is not enough of a reason to use it.

Comment: That got rid of my error at line 35, but now I have the error, `non-member allRobotNames cannot be declared mutable. `

Comment: sorry, I did both of your suggestions at once. I didn't put allRobotNames mutable, but I did put robotName as mutable, and put reset() as non-const.

Comment: I edited the answer to only have robotName as `mutable`.  But honestly, isn't this changing the state of the object that will impact the user of the object?  If it does, you're violating the `const` contract that you're stating.  Why not just a `get_name` function which would be const, and a `set_name` that would be non-const?

Comment: i don't think `mutable` is appropriate here. The `reset()` function shouldn't be declared `const` in the first place as its intent is to modify the function. Looking at just the code provided the `robotName` member should be initialized in the default constructor and an additional constructor added to take a name argument. the use of `mutable` here just promotes the continued use of a bad implementation.

Comment: _"If you're using mutable to just make it possible to change the values of class members, that is not enough of a reason to use it."_ What other reason could there be?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - What I mean is that if you're willy-nilly making members mutable just to make it easier to circumvent the const contract, then that is an abuse of mutable.

Comment: @Lightness: you could be using some API out of your control which requires non-constness, but doesn't actually modify the data. Or you could be hiding the changes from outside code. Or you could be maintaining some sort of cache which doesn't actually impact the results, but improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

`name()` and `reset()` are constant functions, that means they cannot alter the state of the `*this` object.